# What do the "(?<!…)" symbols mean in a Python regular expression?

Tags: python, regex, syntax

I have the regular expression `re.sub(r"(?<!\s)\}", r' }', string)`. What does the `(?<!…)` sequence indicate?

Comment: Actually it's a negative lookbehind https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's a bit more than the `<` symbol, in the regular expression you've provided.

What's actually there is a 'Negative lookbehind': `(?<!    )` which is saying "What's before this is not...".  In your case, it's looking for `}`, on the condition that what comes before it is not `\s` - whitespace (tabs, spaces...)

Answer (score 8):

Its a lookback. See the explanation here: http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#negative-lookbehind

Quoted from the source:

> **Negative Lookbehind After the Match:** `\d{3}(?<!USD\d{3})`
>   **Explanation:** `\d{3}` matches *100*, then the negative lookbehind `(?<!USD\d{3})` asserts that at that position in the string, what immediately precedes is not the characters "*USD*" then three digits.

Comment: @ChristopherKyleHorton For some reason the block quotes doesnt like the escaped characters and removes all text after the \d. Any way you can edit?

Comment: A spot opened in the queue and I was able to edit this for you. For your reference, you may wish to [see the changes I made in Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44395127/revisions) so you can do these on your own in the future.

Comment: @ChristopherKyleHorton Thank you, extremely useful for doing next time.